# Why does GTK change the c-cedil? Is it GTK?

Tags: keyboard-layout, special-characters

I have a very old silly problem when working with browsers in KDE in Fedora, and I was never able to fix it, no mater how hard I googled for the solution.

I use two keyboard Layouts, one is

```
 us English (US)
```

which I use to write normal ASCII text, and the other is

```
 us English (US, intl., with dead keys)
```

that I use to write in Portuguese and Spanish, because of the accents. So when I write `'a` I actually get `á`.

It turns out that Portuguese has a c-cedil `ç`, that I write by typing `'c` in all my consoles, xterms, and programs. Except for browsers, where `'c` gives me `ć`.

Why is this mixed behaviour? How can I get `ç` when typing `'c` in browsers?

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/363115/how-to-type-latin-small-letter-c-with-cedilla

Comment: @JohanMyréen: There are lots of things that I tried there that didn't work, but at the end one did. Although this is then a duplicate question, I will add the solution below. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion of Johan Myréen above, I found a solution in the link he provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/605165/628393) by Gunnar Hjalmarsson, but with a caveat. So I will put it here.

It is suggested in the thread to place the line

```
export LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
```

in the file `~/.profile`. This works with the `ç`, but messes up with all my Latin1 (ISO8859-1) consoles and all the other applications, since the whole thing begins working UTF8. My only problem was with GTK applications, mainly browsers.

So the simple solution is to launch the browser with the `export LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8` line in a bash script, e.g.,

```
 #!/bin/bash
 export LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
 firefox
```

or from the command line (reverting the export after the browser is closed).

Unfortunately, Gunnar's suggestion for the `~/.XCompose` file did not work, because it also messes up my Latin1 encoding consoles.